# Neo4j: How to add a list with label names and make sure that an asset has a label that is part of the list?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have one label called "BusinessAssetTypes". It specifies which assets are part of Business Assets. Also there is a label "DataAssetTypes" that specifies which labels are part of data assets.

In the following query I manually say: a business asset can be an acronym, business term or KPI and a data asset can be column, table or schema --> find the relation between a business asset and a data asset.

```
MATCH (ba)-[rel]->(da)
WHERE (ba:Acronym OR ba:BusinessTerm OR ba:KPI) 
AND (da:Column OR da:Table OR da:Schema)
RETURN ba, da
```

The thing is that the list of business assets changes. That is why it should not be added manually in the WHERE clause, but be inserted from the label "BusinessAssetTypes".

I have tried to create a list and use the list later in the query:

```
MATCH (bat:BusinessAssetType)
WITH collect(bat.name) AS baType
MATCH (dat: DataAssetTypes)
WITH collect(dat.name) AS daType
MATCH (ba)-[rel]->(da)
WHERE ba IS PART OF baType
AND da IS PART OF daType
RETURN ba, da
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you have a dynamic list of target business asset labels and a dynamic list of data asset labels. So I think what you would be looking for is:

```
MATCH (bat:BusinessAssetType)
MATCH (dat: DataAssetTypes)
WITH collect(DISTINCT bat.name) AS baType, 
     collect(DISTINCT dat.name) AS daType 

MATCH (ba)-[rel]->(da) 
WHERE any(x in labels(ba) WHERE x IN baType)
    AND any(y in labels(da) WHERE y in daType)
RETURN ba, da
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It is very helpful!!
Do you have an idea how names of business assets (in cypher: collect(DISTINCT bat.name) AS baType) can be collected without the blank line? 
The reason is that the labels do not have spaces and therefore are not found by the WHERE statement. 
Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. This sort of sounds like an issue with your data not the cypher. Are you saying that the name property values (e.g. bat.name) have spaces but the labels don't? You can remove spaces by using `replace(bat.name, " ", "")`

Comment: If possible, it also sounds like your database could benefit from being refactored. Considered either linking your business asset nodes directly to the asset type nodes or as @cybersam suggested, use multiple labels on the business asset nodes

Answer (score 0):

A node can have multiple labels.

Your "business asset" nodes should all have the `BusinessAsset` label (not `BusinessAssetType`, since all labels are "types" anyway) AND a second label for a specific business asset sub-type (like `KPI`). Similarly for data assets.

For example, when creating the nodes:

```
CREATE (ba:BusinessAsset:KPI {id: 123, ...})
CREATE (da:DataAsset:Table {id:234, ...})
```

and when querying for all connected business and data assets:

```
MATCH (ba:BusinessAsset)--(da:DataAsset)
RETURN ba, da
```